# Wait until loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a table by jQuery load then zebra the table
but the content of table is loaded but the zebra fails. If the page is loaded and the table exists the zebra function works.

```
$("#processTab").load("URL");

$(".Innertable tr:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#eee");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to zebra your table after the table has been loaded. To detect when the table has been loaded use the callback of the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.